# Make URL insensitive using URL Rewriting in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to make `URL insensitive` using `URL Rewriting` in php.
I am new to php so I don't have that much idea but I got some code for `URL Rewriting` to remove .php from url. I have written it in `.htaccess` file.
What changes I will need to do in this code to make URL completely insensitive ?
For example, if url is hello.php then It should work as Hello.php , hello, Hello, HELLO etc.

**My Code :**

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to handle case insensitive requirement:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What URL did you try and what is location of this .htaccess file? It must be in document root.

Comment: I have shared hosting so there is only one `.htaccess` in main document root. Main file is Agape.php, I tried Agape and agape but both are showing 404 error.

Comment: Start providing full details `still same issue` cannot help you.

Comment: Using this exact rule I can open: `/User.PHP` OR `/User.php` OR `/user.php`. You just need to make sure it is placed right and there is no conflicting rule.